# Quantum wave interference in 3d space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Why, in the double slit experiment, is there an interference pattern only along the horizontal axis and not along both axes?

Comment: Note that if you rotate the slit 90$^\circ$, you'll get a vertical interference pattern. Clearly then, it has *something* to do with the *orientation* of the slit.

Comment: Note that you are assuming that the slits are infinitely long along their length.

Answer (score 1):

Because the experimental set up is made with vertical slits. Generally these slits are far taller than the separation between them. When the experimental set up is made with pinholes you will get circular interference patterns.

Try doing both, just get a toy laser pointer and start making slits and pinholes.